# How to run ESLint in a specific directory within my project with GitHub Actions

Tags: javascript, github, eslint, github-actions

I've been trying to get ESLint to automatically run from GitHub Actions in my project. My project structure looks like this

```
.github/workflows
     /api
     /frontend
```

ESLint is installed in both directories, the /frontend using TSLint, and the API using ESLint. When I cd to /api in my console and run ESLint it works great, but when I run it in GitHub Actions, which is ran from the workflow file in project root, I get an error saying

```
(The package "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin" was not found when loaded as a Node module from the directory "D:\a\github-username\project\frontend".)
```

Now I don't know why it tries to get a package from /frontend, while it's only supposed to run in /api.

My workflow looks like this

```
name: Test API

on:
  push:
    paths:
    - 'api/**'
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    paths:
    - 'api/**'
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: windows-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x, 12.x]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - run: npm ci
      working-directory: ./api
    - run: npm run build --if-present
      working-directory: ./api
    - run: npx eslint .
      working-directory: ./api
    - run: npm test
      working-directory: ./api
```

I've tried  doing just 'api', './api', and setting working-directory in 'defaults', but the error persists.